# Jquery change() parameter

Tags: jquery, parameters

I have a problem, i create a div which can be created by the user alot of times.

```
var innerdiv = $('<div>');
innerdiv.attr('class','dropzoneobject');
innerdiv.attr('onclick', 'changeText(this)').appendTo(div);
```

This div has a onclick action with as parameter this.

```
function changeText(object) {
var editor = document.getElementById('editortools');
var display = editor.style.display = 'block';
var text = object.firstChild;   

$('#color').change(function(object) {
var color = document.getElementById('color').value;
var text = object.firstChild;
text.style.color = color;   
    });
            }
```

In the function changeText i can alert and do everything with the object parameter i got from the div with the onclick event.

BUT in the change() function.. the object parameter is gone ! :(

My question: how can i get the same object in the second function?

```
function changeText(object) {
alert(object);
//I can see the object !
$('#color').change(function() {
alert(object);
// no object here :C
});
}
```

Fixed it :) here is the code for peeps with the same problem

```
function changeText(object) {
            selectedDiv = object;
            $("#editortools").fadeIn();
        }

        var selectedDiv = null;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#color').change(function() {
                if(selectedDiv != null){
                    selectedDiv.style.color = $('#color').val();
                }
            });
```

Comment: why are you using document.getElementById() while using jQuery. Try jQuery('#color').

Comment: `var innerdiv = $('<div>');` looks like it might be wrong. AFAIK you do not need the brackets in the jquery selector. `var innerdiv = $('div');` should work to select all `div` elements.

Comment: var innerdiv = $('div'); <- is making a new div element

Comment: In your second block of code above, you have `$('#color').change(function(object) { ... });` You are taking in object as a parameter to the function. jQuery passes in the event object as that parameter, so when you reference object, you are referencing the one passed into the handler function, not the one in your main function. Try taking that parameter out.

Comment: Other than that, the way you are adding the onclick handler to innerDiv should be changed. innerDiv.click(function () { changeText(this); });

Comment: innerDiv.click(function () { changeText(this); }); did the trick !! 

much thanks for that ! well i dont know if it was the combination of all your solutions or just this one but many thanks !

Comment: hmmm now i have another problem.. yes it worked, but when i make 2 divs (innerdiv) and click on one div, and change the color the other div will also change color !!